# Add new Alexa skill for Screen Sample App

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I would like to ask that is any possible to add new skill to Smart Sample APP:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-smart-screen-sdk/ubuntu.html

I know that I need use below webside to create new skill

https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console:
[image: https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console]

My new skill will need capability relate to volume control

How I can connect new skill with test app

What is procedure in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The smart screen SDK is for building Alexa-enabled devices with the Alexa Voice Service. You'll build a device or virtual device with it.

Custom skills are built with the Alexa Skills Kit. It's a separate domain from Alexa Voice Service.

You'll need to log into the (virtual) device with an Amazon account to use it. Then to use your skill (if it's not published), it'll need to be in a developer account tied to the same email address as the account logged into the device. This allows you to test your skill during development.

Answer (score 0):

I builed SKD on Raspberry and start Sample App I found extention relate to discoball and power controler

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/device-makers/2020/04/create-a-sample-alexa-built-in-disco-ball-with-smart-home-for-av

And it is work fine, I can tell: Alexa turn on discoball

How I can extend skill of discoball device

I would like to tell: Alexa mute discoball or Alexa set discoball volume to 100

I would like to add python scrpit to each command

With file contatin discoball capabilitis what I shall add to code ?